# How to split a statement across two lines in Symfony2 validation.yml file

Tags: symfony, yaml

I am trying to write in a properties validation option for a form in a Symfony2 bundle (in the standard src/site/BundleName/Resources/config/validation.yml file) and I am wondering how to split a statement into two lines. As is, this:

```
department:
        - Type: string
        - Choice:
            choices: ['Customer Service', 'Development', 'Finance', 'Human Resources', 'Marketing', 'Production', 'Quality Management', 'Research', 'Sales']
```

compiles correctly. However, when I try to split the statement as such:

```
department:
    - Type: string
    - Choice:
        choices: ['Customer Service', 'Development', 'Finance', 'Human Resources', 'Marketing', 'Production',
                  'Quality Management', 'Research', 'Sales']
```

(with 'Quality Management...' being moved to the next line and indented) I get the following error:

```
Malformed inline YAML string ['Customer Service', 'Development', 'Finance', 'Human Resources', 'Marketing', 'Production', at line 25 (near "choices: ['Customer Service', 'Development', 'Finance', 'Human Resources', 'Marketing', 'Production',")
500 Internal Server Error - ParseException
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for splitting up a line/statement in a .yml file? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a backslash will let you escape the carriage return, but IMHO, you should do this:

```
department:
    - Type: string
    - Choice:
        choices:
            - 'Customer Service'
            - 'Development'
            - 'Finance'
            - 'Human Resources'
            - 'Marketing'
            - 'Production'
            - 'Quality Management'
            - 'Research'
            - 'Sales'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the backslash does not escape the carriage return. I will vote your answer up by 1 when I have enough reputation to do so, though :p